# Backbone Marionette Composite View Rendering Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to render a list with a Marionette CompositeView.  I am not sure why the rendered list just has an item displaying the word `result`.  I was expecting the first item to display `Level 1`.

Here is a fiddle to my current code:  http://jsfiddle.net/16L1hen4/

Here is my JS, template, and data:

JavaScript:

```
var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({
    mainRegion: '#main' 
});

var TreeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({    
});

var TreeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TreeModel,

    url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/backbone-tree/collections/tree?apiKey=somekey'

});

var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function() { 
        console.log(this.collection); 

    },

    tagName: 'ul',

    template: _.template( $('#tree-template').html() )
});

var treeCollection = new TreeCollection();
treeCollection.fetch().done(function () {
    var treeView = new TreeView({collection: treeCollection});
    App.mainRegion.show(treeView);    
});
```

Template:

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="tree-template">
    <li><%- name %></li>
</script>
```

JSON Data:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54adab80e4b0aa674b256836"
    },
    "name": "Level 1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Child 1 - Level 2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Jon - Level 3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mary - Level 3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Child 2 - Level 2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Bill - Level 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: A Compositeview takes a collection of Backbone Models to render rather than a single model. In order to nest models, you can also use a collectionview within a compositeview.

Comment: @KimGysen Thank you.  I editted the question and the code to use a `Backbone.Collection` instead of a `Backbone.Model`.  I still do know understand why the first item displays the word `result` though.

Comment: Its a small change, and not really related to the actual question, but you can refer to the template directly with a `template: "#tree-template"` instead of the underscore method; Marionette will automatically find the template for you using underscore, if it is a string reference to a DOM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a CompositeView to display a Collection, but you need to define a `childView` to render the models

```
var LeafView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    // ...
});

var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView: LeafView
})
```

here is an updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/6ok1rptq/

Now the "result" showing in the html, without being familiar with the underscore source, I believe this is caused by the fact that the `data` given to the template is null, and a quick look at the source of underscore shows that it is using `with`

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-148

"If a variable is not specified, place data values in local scope."

Meaning that the template can't find a "name" variable, and will instead look it up in the global scope (`window`)

Result is just the name of the jsfiddle iframe containing the result of the fiddle

```
<iframe name="result" ...>
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation.  I didn't realize that a CompositeView required an childView.

Answer (score 2):

Read the marrionnete docs a bit closer - you need a childView defined....

Comment: I must have misunderstood the docs.  I thought that a template would be enough, and if a childView was used it would just be appended inside the template.

Comment: I'm glead you got it sorted out! Personally i think marrionnete is the backbone's best friend:)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but I assume that the error lies with the fact that you didn't define a Marionette Itemview on the CompositeView.

The logical structure is to pass the Compositeview a collection as you did in the question, and the models will be rendered in separate itemviews.
In the itemview you can call:

```
this.model.get("property");
```

To access the properties from within the view.

Comment: Thanks @KimGysen.  I did not realize that an ItemView was needed for a CompositeView. I thought that defining a template would be enough.

Comment: @Mdd You're welcome. For Compositeview you can define a template because it allows you to create a wrapper div and define a parent element in this wrapper div in which you want to render the itemviews. You cannot do this with a collection view.