# Backbone Marionette - Log Model in Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am wondering how to log the model used in a Backbone.Marionette CompositeView's template?

The `<% console.log(model) %>` I am using causes an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: model is not defined`

Is there a way to log the content of the model from the template?

Here is a fiddle to my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/16L1hen4/

Here is my Template and JavaScript

Template:

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="tree-template">
    <li><%- name %></li>

    <% //This console.log fails and I don't know why %>
    <% console.log('inside template model =',model) %>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({
    mainRegion: '#main' 
});

var TreeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({    
});

var TreeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TreeModel,

    url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/backbone-tree/collections/tree?apiKey=akey'

});

// Tree branch view
var CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({    
    tagName: 'ul',

    template: _.template( $('#tree-template').html() )
});

// Tree root view
var CollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({   
    tagName: 'div',

    className: 'js-tree-root',

    childView: CompositeView,
});

var treeCollection = new TreeCollection();
treeCollection.fetch().done(function () {
    var collectionView = new CollectionView({collection: treeCollection});
    App.mainRegion.show(collectionView);
```

});

**Edit:**  In a regular Backbone.View I can pass the model to the data as a property.  Notice in this example that the View's model is passed to the template with a `data` property which can be logged in the template.  This could be useful in the template to test for the existance of properties on the model.  I am not sure how to do this using a Marionette CompositeView

```
var jsonData = {
    "color": "red"
};

var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({    
});

var TheView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#main',

    tagName: 'ul',

    template: _.template( $('#the-template').html() ),

    render: function () {
        var tmpl = this.template({data: this.model.toJSON()});

        this.$el.html( tmpl );
    }
});

var theModel = new TheModel(jsonData);

var theView = new TheView({model: theModel});
theView.render();


<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="the-template">
    <li><%- data.color %></li>

    <% //Log the current model that the template uses %>
    <% console.log('template model =',data) %>
</script>
```

Comment: What is wrong with logging them when the models are initialized?

Comment: @KimGysen I will update the question but here is a fiddle using a regular Backbone.View.  Notice that I pass the model to the template with a property I have named `data`.  Inside the template I can log `<% console.log(data) %> and do conditional testing based off of properties.  I am wondering how to do this using a Marionette CompositeView. Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Nirvanachain/exryqwmf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to be related to the anwser I posted on your question here : [Backbone Marionette Composite View Rendering Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831965/backbone-marionette-composite-view-rendering-template/27832375?noredirect=1#comment44089000_27832375)

and is cause by the same issue. `model` being undefined in the template context.
The data passed to your template is the following:

```
{_id: Object, name: "Level 1", children: Array[2]}
```

and `model` is undefined in this context.

If you want to log/control the data passed to your template you have should use [SerializeData](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.itemview.html#itemview-serializedata) in such a way:

```
var CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({    
    tagName: 'ul',
    serializeData: function(){
        var data = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.prototype.serializeData.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    },
    template: _.template( $('#tree-template').html() )
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I editted the question to better explain what I am trying to do.  Here is a fiddle using a regular `Backbone.View` where I pass the model to a template in an assigned property.  In this instance I named the property `data`.  I am not sure how to do this in Marionette with a CompositeView, but I think it could be useful to testing to see if properties exist on the model.  http://jsfiddle.net/exryqwmf/

Comment: in this case you can do
serializeData: function(){
    return {data: this.model.toJSON();
}
http://jsfiddle.net/16L1hen4/13/

Comment: Thank you!!!  I had not seen the serializeData method before.  Is that available on all Marionette Views?

Comment: No, only to `ItemView` and its children (`LayoutView`)